# std::sort com função de comparação

Tags: c++, classificação, stl

Estudando um pouco sobre a STL me deparei com a função `std::sort` que pode receber uma função de comparação.

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

Como funciona essa função de comparação ? E como ela é utilizada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em C++ std::sort é um "algoritmo", não uma função. Isto é, std::sort é uma função genérica declarada como um template.

O uso da função de comparação é necessário quando não existe uma ordem intrínseca a ser usada ao comparar os elementos. Esta ordem intrínseca seria definida pelo operador "<".

No exemplo abaixo, não é possível comparar duas instâncias da classe Person: não é possível fazer "if (p1 < p2)" a não ser que o operador para a classe Person seja escrito.

A função de comparação não precisa ser necessariamente um "operator <", qualquer função que receba 2 parâmetros do tipo Person e retorne "bool" pode ser utilizada. No exemplo abaixo é utilizada a função "isAgeLess" para "comparar" duas instâncias da classe Person.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Person
{
   string name;
   int age;
};

bool isAgeLess(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
{
   return p1.age < p2.age;
}

vector<Person> people
{
   { "Maria",   17 },
   { "Joao",    15 },
   { "Antonio", 53 },
   { "Carlos" , 13 },
};

int main()
{
   sort(people.begin(), people.end(), isAgeLess);

   cout << "*\n";

   for (const auto& p : people)
   {
      cout << "* nome=" << p.name << "\t idade=" << p.age << '\n';
   }

   cout << "*\n";
}
```

Resultado:

```
*
* nome=Carlos    idade=13
* nome=Joao      idade=15
* nome=Maria     idade=17
* nome=Antonio   idade=53
*
```

Comment: No caso, de forma resumida, quando a função retorna `false` os valores são permutados no vetor e a mesma é executada sobre o vetor até que retorne `true` para todos os elementos?

Comment: Significa que eu posso ordenar um conjunto de inteiros, sem que a ordem seja ascendente ou descendente? eu posso definir essa ordem?

Comment: @Andrey França: isso.

Comment: @Anderson: a função de  comparação é utilizada da mesma forma que seria utilizada o operador "<": se "func(a,b)" retorna true, isso significa que "a < b", se retorna false então isso significa que "a >=b", e esses resultados são utilizados para classificar os elementos.