# Qual a finalidade da função compare da função qsort do C++?

Tags: c++

Veja abaixo um exemplo de aplicação da função `qsort`, utilizando uma função `compare`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;


int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );

}

int main()
{
    int vet[]={3,2,1};
    qsort(vet,3,sizeof(int),compare);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    cout<<endl<<vet[i];

}
```

1. Para que serve a função `compare`?
2. O que são os argumentos `void` desta função?
3. Qual a utilidade destes argumentos?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199670/5878 (pelo o que entendi, basicamente a diferença entre `qsort` e `std::sort` é que a primeira funciona com uma função de comparação retornando `int` e a segunda retornando `bool`). As implementações das duas pode diferenciar também. Não tenho certeza, só achei que poderia ser uma pergunta legal para você analisar até responderem esta.

Comment: Na verdade, `std::sort` também aceita função/lambdas para comparação: `std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](int a, int b) {return a > b; });`. `qsort` deveria ser evitada, porque além de geralmente mais lenta, ela não é type-safe e não funciona com a STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qsort em C e C++, pretende lidar com arrays de tipo genérico.
Para tal precisa de:

- lidar com tipos genéricos -- para tal lida com o endereço do
  valor em causa (daí o uso de "apontadores genérico" convencionalmente
  designado por  "apontador para void" --  `void * v` )
- saber como copiar elementos (daí o parámetro `sizeof(int)`)
- precisa de saber se um par de elementos está na ordem certa (daí a função de comparação)

Para cada tipo podemos pretender ordenar de formas diferentes. Considerando apenas o caso de strings (ver por exemplo as opções do comando `sort` do unix...) -- podemos ordenar:

- crescente / decrescente
- alfabetico / numérico
- ignore-case ou não
- ignorando espaços
- "version" - sorting
- em modo dicionário
- ter conta locales, ("ç" = "c", ..., ou não )

No teu exemplo passaste uma função que compara um par de apontadores para 
inteiros.